# jquery pass across something?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Load form elements through ajax, from onchange event of drop down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344747/jquery-load-form-elements-through-ajax-from-onchange-event-of-drop-down-box)

I have a dropdown form which when the selection is changed, that div hides and another appears.

How would I get the value of the drop down to appear on the next div?

For example:

```
<div id="fruit">
    <select name="comp" id="comp" class="text">
        <option value="29">Apple</option>
        <option value="160">Pear</option>
        <option value="132">Orange</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="display">
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like it to pass the ID to a page, for example `fruit.php?id=132`

This page would then have some PHP in which I can do, to return the other values from the database.

I need it to pass `#comp` value over to fruit.php (via ajax?) and then return the data to `#display`

How could I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: create a function with change() and then put a your ajax call in there. That will give enough to search stack and find your answer as it has been asked before. Also look at http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#comp").change(function() {
    $("#display").load("fruit.php?id="+$("#comp").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#comp').change(function(){

    $.get('fruit.php',{id: $(this).val()}, function( result ){

        $('#display').html( result );

    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a `.load()`

I will add jquery.ajax method

```
var compVal=$("#comp").val();
$.ajax({
  url: "fruit.php?id="+compVal,
  type: "get", // you can also use post
  success: function( result ){ // result contains the response of fruit.php page
    $('#display').html( result );
  }
});
```

[http://jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)